# Running an executable in a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and am reading through The Docker Book by Turnbull.
Essentially, I have a grasp of the terms and process of how containers work and how images work in Transmission Protocol and virtualized operating systems.

however, my dockerfile is not running an executable which is local, and I can not figure out how to add my local executable into my container's /bin directory.

My goal:  I would like to add name.exe into the /bin directory of my container.  Then I would like to have a docker file that is

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER me@gmail.com
RUN ["name.exe", "input1", "output"]
```

and have my container run my program, and create an output.
My goal is to them put my container onto my repo, and share it, along with all of the /bin programs I have written.

However, I am not able to do so.

Comment: just to make sure, your `name.exe` is not windows executable, is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bear in mind that `name.exe` have to be in same directory as your dockerfile. [From the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy):

> The `<src>` path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot `COPY ../something /something`, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

Your dockerfile could look like this then:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER me@gmail.com
COPY name.exe /bin/
CMD ["/bin/name.exe", "input1", "output"]
```

You can build it then like this:

```
docker build --tag=me/my-image .
```

And when you run it (`docker run me/my-image`), it will run `/bin/name.exe input1 output`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD name.exe /bin/name.exe
ENTRYPOINT["name.exe"]
CMD["input1","input2"]
```

But this input1 input2 have to be on docker too, otherwise you have to add -v when running

Answer (score 1):

Basically the "add" command copies a file from your local system into the docker image.

See here for more:
https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add

Comment: what is the difference between ADD and COPY? I have used the COPY command, and the file is copied into my container, however it will not run when I initiate an interactive shell.  I greatly appreciate your advice. thank you.