# Running exe in Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am a beginner in docker and looking for some help.
I have a windows based application which I want to run on container. I have my bat file which starts my server exe and the file configurations written in this form 
`-start backend.exe -listen="192.X.X.X:80" -dev=true -mysql="user:pass@tcp(192.x.x.x:3306)/db`

Now as I want to containerize the app I am confused how to run the and pass the above parameters in a `Dockerfile`.

I know that the bat file and will not run in linux based container

What I am thinking so for is somethings like below but confused about giving the parameters in `CMD`

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["backend.exe", "listen", "192.x.x.x”, "dev", "true"]
```

Getting idea from this query at stackoverflow [Running an executable in a dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291826/running-an-executable-in-a-dockerfile)

Comment: is it possible to run exe in linux based container ?